# AngularJS basic auth

Tags: angularjs, basic-authentication

Why do i get a 401 with this? The credentials are correct.

```
  app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + btoa("xxx:yyy");
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.withCredentials = true;
  }
```

....

```
 $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: url
    data: data,
})
```

Comment: Would you want to use something like https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64 instead of the browser's btoa function to support older browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Try including your `Authorization` header inside `$http` like:

```
 $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: url
    data: data,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("xxx:yyy")},
})
```